# android radiogroup not wrap content if there are much radio buttons in group

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

What i want is my radio list auto break to next line if it meets the border of screen.
but the result came to be like that (i had 8 radio btns):
[image]

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/card_no_claim"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_card_number"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio50plus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio50palus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio5f0plus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio50pluas"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rahdio50plus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radieo50plus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio50plaus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio50palaus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_radio_button" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

im an android newbie please help. thank you so much. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please post the source code and not the image of the source code! ;)